# C# ByPassing if(condition) statement without filling the condition?! magical things happens?

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview, boolean-logic, datagridviewcheckboxcell

(`dgv_configCH` is a winform DataGridView). As you can see in the picture below, the VS executor is within the if's brackets with a false condition. Actually, the VS executor doesn't enter after checking the condition, but just before leaving the function. In this program, my purpose is simply being able to use the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` because `dgv_configCH[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()` always returns `true` in the `dgv_configCH_CellValueChanged` event.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to become false after CommitEdit()?

Comment: @IndritKello Committing is exactly what makes the cell "clean" again ... so I'd say perfectly expected image.

Comment: I screen recorded what's happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIevvCGDV48 For more clarification I press F11 too fast but what it does is : just before leaving the function, after the ending bracket it goes back to the line dgv_configCH.CommitEdit...

Answer (score 0):

Well it was true, when the compiler hit the line - for sure ;)
Please change to

var isDirty = this.dgv_configCH.IsCurrentCellDirty;
if (isDirty)

you will see, you changed state with commitedit() and so you cannot see the correct if condition anymore in the line you stopped.

Comment: it looks to me like you hit the method twice - first time it exits with isDirty false and second it lands in the condition - right?

if so is it the same thread? if not you can try to synchronize the calls in the Method.